# Is there an event that fires once all dependency properties are set?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, winrt-xaml

My control has 5 dependency properties. I set them in XAML like this:

```
<MyControl Prop1="1" Prop2="2" Prop3="3" Prop4="4" />
```

As you can see, I am only setting 4 of the 5 properties in XAML.

What I need to find is some mechanism to indicate that all the properties set in XAML have been processed. With this event, I can run my SetItAllUp() method.

**Option 1**. Use the DP setter

FAIL: Not an option because I cannot call SetItAllUp() but one time. This also has the side effect of activating based on the ordinal declaration of each DP in the XAML. If there *is* some type of chaining or dependency between my properties, this undermines it.

**Option 2**. Use the DP setter, and test all values are set

FAIL: Not an option because sometimes certain DP values are optional - let's just pretend that the logic necessary to determine if optional values are properly set or not is too complex to implement this solution for now, please.

**Option 3**. Use MyControl.Loaded

FAIL: Not an option because this fires too early. In fact, every event I can see fires too early. It is almost as if the object is created and then something under the hood starts to set the DP values based on the declarations.

---

### **Update**! Loaded is the solution. My question was flawed.

There's some event or something, right?
// Thanks

Comment: Load isn't fired until after the properties are set, so why is it too early?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loaded works fine. Sorry for the confusion.

I tested this class:

```
public class MyPath : Path
{
    public MyPath()
    {
        Loaded += MyPath_Loaded;
    }

    void MyPath_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Loaded");
    }
    public int Test1
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(Test1Property); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(Test1Property, value);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Test1");
        }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty Test1Property =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Test1", typeof(int), typeof(MyPath),
        new PropertyMetadata(DependencyProperty.UnsetValue, null));

    public int Test2
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(Test2Property); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(Test2Property, value);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Test2");
        }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty Test2Property =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Test2", typeof(int), typeof(MyPath),
        new PropertyMetadata(DependencyProperty.UnsetValue, null));

    public int Test3
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(Test3Property); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(Test3Property, value);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Test3");
        }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty Test3Property =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Test3", typeof(int), typeof(MyPath),
        new PropertyMetadata(DependencyProperty.UnsetValue, null));

    public int Test4
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(Test4Property); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(Test4Property, value);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Test4");
        }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty Test4Property =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Test4", typeof(int), typeof(MyPath),
        new PropertyMetadata(DependencyProperty.UnsetValue, null));

    public int Test5
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(Test5Property); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(Test5Property, value);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Test5");
        }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty Test5Property =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Test5", typeof(int), typeof(MyPath),
        new PropertyMetadata(DependencyProperty.UnsetValue, null));
}
```

With this XAML:

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundBrush}">
    <local:MyPath Test1="1" Test2="2" Test3="3" Test4="4" />
</Grid>
```

And got this Trace:

```
Test1
Test2
Test3
Test4
Loaded
```

And it turns out Loaded works just fine.
My previous testing must have had some other factor.
My simplified test shows Loaded seems perfect.